# StructureMap configure

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I am sorry to ask silly question, but I don't know how to define my question in the search engine.

I am using StructureMap like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.For(typeof(IUtils)).Use(typeof(EFUtils));
    });
```

Now I need to add something like this to the configuration:

```
x.For<IList<IMovementsManager>>().Return(
    new List<IMovementsManager>() { 
        new TaskManager(),
        new WarehouseManager()
    });
```

What is the syntax to do so?

**EDIT:**
In order to make it more clear, whenever the user asks for `IList<IMovementsManager>` the StructureMap should return the following instance:

```
new List<IMovementsManager>() { 
            new TaskManager(),
            new WarehouseManager()
        }
```

Comment: The syntax in you For statement is not compiling. Could you explain what you are trying to do? What interface are you requesting from structuremap and what are you expecting to get back?

Comment: why would you use StructureMap for this? Creating a collection is not a dependency. Shouldn't this be in a service of some sort?

Comment: Maybe GetAllInstances<IMovementsManager> is what you're looking for?

Comment: @RPM1984 - I do it where I work. We have 'KPI's which are registered like this, depending on which assemblies are deployed for different clients, and using `GetAllInstances<IKpi>()` and iterating over them to display allows us to plugin different KPIs with as much effort as it takes to drop some assemblies in the bin directory. (if that makes sense)

Comment: @Phill - not really, but i take your word for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want (I don't have VS handy to quickly test) is to scan them like:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(c => c.Scan(x =>
             {
                 x.TheCallingAssembly();
                 x.AddAllTypesOf<IMovementsManager>();
             }));
```

Here's the StructureMap documentation for registering all concrete instance of a type:

http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section5